# Is it's good practice to declaration new component in template?

Tags: vue.js

I have Vue `template` that that should send some data to server. I would like to move it in separate vue instance. Like:

```
var authorization = new Vue({   
    //
})
```

Would it be good practice to place some data binding from new component with data from `template`?

I create `app` and decided to put in it `auth` (declarated in template). Is it's good?

What is the best way to put some sub-apps-modules in Vue App?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question, but if I understand you right, you wan´t a seperate app to comunicate with the server, so with your database?

If that is the case, then you should just work with an API which includes services you can call from your app with Axios.