# How get data from from Vue Template?

Tags: vue.js

I have got next HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <component :is="currentView"></component>
</div>
```

Vue code:

```
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
      template: `
                  <input v-model="username">
          `});
Vue.component('guestmenu', GuestMenu);

var App = new Vue ({
   el: '#app',
  // template: '<usermenu></usermenu>',
  data: 
    {
      currentView: "guestmenu",
      username: ""
    }
  })
```

I need to get `username` from `v-model`. The problem that all examples show how to get it's directly, but my data placed in template...

http://jsfiddle.net/u9L569ku/

Comment: When you say you want to get username from v-model, you've already done that. Data object username is bound two ways because of the v-model directive.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you show me how to output it's value...

Comment: `this.username` will give its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what you want to achieve. Basically, there is a parent-child realtionship in your example but the communication was not set up correctly. The *username* in your component was not bound to the *username* in the Vue instance's data.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9L569ku/2/)

html

```
<div id="app">
   <component :username.sync="username" :is="currentView"> </component>
     {{username}}
</div>
```

javascript

```
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
    props : ['username'],
    template: `<input v-model="username">`
});

Vue.component('guestmenu', GuestMenu);

var App = new Vue ({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      currentView: "guestmenu",
      username: ""
    }
  })
```

Comment: Could you also look at this question. It's a little bit related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697989/is-its-good-practice-to-declaration-new-component-in-template